# Scala constructor with default value

Tags: scala

Is there any possibility to do in Scala something like:

```
class Class(x: Int, y: Z = new Z(x))
```

I get the error: `not found value x`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve looks like an auxiliary constructor.

Your code then will look like this if you use one:

```
class Class(x: Int, y: Z){
  def this(x: Int) = this(x, new Z(x))
}
```